# What object is returned by using Fetch Request in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Apple Documents says "**If a context already contains a managed object for an object returned from a fetch, then the existing managed object is returned in the fetch results**"

My Question is If I have updatd the object in the context but not saved the context yet then what object will Fetch Request return? Updated object from Context or New one from Datastore.

Comment: Are you setting the fetch request to include pending changes? You can run some tests to see what objects are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the `includesPendingChanges` setting of the fetch request. By default,
`includesPendingChanges` is `YES`, which means that the fetch will get currently unsaved
changes.

However, if you use the `NSDictionaryResultType` result type for the fetch request,
this implicitly implies `includesPendingChanges = NO`, and you will get only results
from the store.

Answer (score 1):

Your quote answers that question; it will be the one in memory. With that comes the caveat that if you make a new `NSManagedObjectContext` and perform the fetch request on that context, you will get the object from the data store.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it returns **Updated object from Context**.

***Note: Due to low reputation i have to put as answer.***